# Android Menu Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I have created a menu with xml and a menu class.  I have a button to select what I want for my game and then I have a start button appear which is meant to start my MainActivity, where the game is.  However that is not working and I am not sure why.  Also is there a way I can click the Button games = (Button) findViewById(R.id.E); and have a value be sent to the MainActivity so that the MainActivity knows the E button was selected?  Here is my following menu:

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

 private static final  int GAME_SELECTOR=0; 
 Intent gamechoice;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selection);
         //get our Radio Button Group
        final Button Startgame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startgame);
        Startgame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Button games = (Button) findViewById(R.id.E);
        //create new selectedColor Intent
        gamechoice = new Intent();
        games.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Startgame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                  
           }
        });

        //set action listener for button
        Startgame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //first create new intent to call ColorSelectorActivity 
    Intent request = new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(request);

   }
  });
    }

}
```

selection.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >    
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Numbers To Press"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/E"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="E" /> 
<Button
    android:id="@+id/startgame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Start Game" />
```

mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView text;
private GridView gridView;
private TextView timerValue;
private Boolean firstclick = false;
private int clicks = 0;
private long startTime = 0L;
private long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
private long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
private long updatedTime = 0L;
private long rowscroll = 135;
//private long rowscroll = 52;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
//private Button buttonclicked;
Random r = new Random();
//private int[] rannumbers_array = new int[32];
private int[] shuffle_array = new int[4];
private String[] items = new String[140];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
    timerValue.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int ranval = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 140; i++)
    {
        if ( (i % 4) == 0)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            {
                shuffle_array[x] = 0;
            }
            do {
                ranval = r.nextInt(100);
            } while((ranval % 2) != 0);
        }
        else
        {
            do {
                ranval = r.nextInt(100);
            } while((ranval % 2) == 0); 
        }
        shuffle_array[j] = ranval;
        j++;
        if(j >= 4)
        {
            j = 0;
            shuffle(shuffle_array);
            do {
               items[k] = Integer.toString(shuffle_array[j]);
               k++;
               j++;
            } while(k <= i);
            j = 0;
        }
        //rannumbers_array[i] = r.nextInt(100);
        //items[i] = Integer.toString(rannumbers_array[i]);
    }
    k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        items[i] = "";
    }
    //for(int i = 12; i < 16; i++)
    //{
    //  items[i] = "Click to finish";
    //}

    gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
    final CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    //buttonclicked = gridAdapter.getbutton();
    //gridView.post(new Runnable() {
    //  public void run() {
    //      gridView.setSelection(gridView.getCount() - 1);
    /// }
    //});


    gridView.setSelection(gridView.getCount() - 1);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(gridView.getPositionForView(view) >= rowscroll && (gridView.getPositionForView(view) <= rowscroll+4))
            {
                if(!firstclick)
                {
                   startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();  
                   customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                   firstclick = true;
                }
                clicks++;
                //view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(4);
                    final int scroll = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item).getHeight();
                    gridView.smoothScrollBy(-scroll, 100);
                    rowscroll = rowscroll - 4;
                    if(clicks==25)
                    {
                        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                        rowscroll = 135;
                    }
            }
            //else
            //{
            //  customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            //}
            //  gridAdapter.getItem(51); //can I make this not clickable or not visible?
            //view.invalidate();

            //view.
            //buttonclicked.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //Button clicked = (Button) gridView.getChildAt(position);
            //gridView.removeViews(gridView.getChildAt(position), 2=);
            //Button clicked = (Button) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //clicked.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            //gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //text.setText((String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
            //Log.i("ITEM_CLICKED", "" + (String) (gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)));
        }
    });

}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        //startTime = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
        updatedTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = (int) (updatedTime / 60000);
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                 + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                 + String.format("%02d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};

// Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
  static void shuffle(int[] ar)
  {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="@string/timerVal"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/myGridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/feedback"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I did not include my code for customadapter since I do not need it for the question.  I am just trying to click the "Start Button" from the Menu class and have it start..or run.. the OnCreate from the MainActivity.  Also I would like the E button from the menu to have a int/bool whatever be sent to the MainActivity when the E button has been selected..is that possible?
I did change my AndroidManifest to

```
android:name="com.example.nextgametest.Menu"
```

so that on startup the app starts at the Menu.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably because your start button is defined as "final". Instead of doing this instantiate the button in on create but make it a field of your Menu Activity. By creating the button in on create and instantiating the onclicklistener for it in on create as well you don't garuntee that it will be available for as long as you like (it can be garbage collected). So in your menu class define

public class Menu extends Activity {

private Button start;

public void onCreate(Bundle s) {

start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourId)

\add the on click listener

}

}

Hope that helps

Comment: I changed it to remove the final and I still get the same thing.  Tells me Unfortunately, game has stopped. and quits out

Comment: You have to make it a field not just remove final

Comment: what do you mean by field

Comment: Like how i wrote code in my answer. You define "start" as a button before onCreate and then instantiate it in onCreate

Comment: I dont see your button or any call for startActivity

Comment: I forgot to update the Manifest..the menu works as expected.  Thank you for your time and help :)